# How to save a changed label when you exit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

In my program I have a preview, and edit side.

When you edit using the text boxes on the edit side(right side) and click "save", It should change the label on the right side (preview side). Although when you exit the program and re-open, all the data you entered has disappeared!,

I have tried the below code and had no luck as my result.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Shared NameBasic As Integer

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    lblNameBasic.Text = Convert.ToString(NameBasic)
End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    NameBasic = txtFirstBasic.Text
    lblNameBasic.Text = Convert.ToString(NameBasic)
End Sub


End Class
```

Also my goal is to have it be able to take it on a flashdrive onto any computer and have that data still saved within the exe. Is this even manageable? (I am more of a web based programmer so I am a bit new to this)

Comment: setting a variable at runtime has no mechanism for saving/persisting the data. You need something to save the data to. Look into `My.Settings`.

Comment: `have that data still saved within the exe` thats a bit of a security problem.  Use `My.Settings`

Comment: @Plutonix Could you give me and example with this, I am using a label that I want to save. And if I used 'My.settings' lets say I took the .exe on a flash drive, plugged it in to a computer would the data that I entered and saved appear?

Comment: What is your data persistence mechanism? - I don't see any here

Comment: I am not exactly sure as well, what I am trying to acomplish here is this.
I will be putting this exe. on a flashdrive when its done, When you type in a text box and click submit, it will then change a label. I want that label to then save, and when you plug the flashdrive in on any computer, I want what you submited on the label to be there from the other computer you were on. Would I need to look into a server? @T.S.

Comment: `all the data you entered` sounds like more than just a label text.  To take the settings with the EXE, I'd serialize a small settings class. perhaps check the drive type/app location to avoid exceptions when it *isnt* on a flash drive and/or *not* able to write there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write values to a text file at the same location of the exe. and read it. you will need both exe and the textfile.

OR

You will need to write a dll on run-time and write some values while closing the application. this will be more secure then the text file. here you will need both exe and dll to be copied into flash drive

OR

the application setting as spoken by others..

Comment: Could I Take the settings file out of the output folder and put it on the flash drive in the same folder as the .exe and all the data would be there?